# How does this lambda feature in java 8 work?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to use java 8 features. While reading [official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#target-types-and-method-arguments) I came across this code

```
static void invoke(Runnable r) {
    r.run();
}

static <T> T invoke(Callable<T> c) throws Exception {
    return c.call();
}
```

and there was a question:

> Which method will be invoked in the following statement?"
>
> `String s = invoke(() -> "done");`

and answer to it was

> The method `invoke(Callable<T>)` will be invoked because that method returns a value; the method `invoke(Runnable)` does not. In this case, the type of the lambda expression `() -> "done"` is `Callable<T>`.

As I understand since `invoke` is expected to return a `String`, it calls Callable's invoke. But, not sure how exactly it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's take a look at the lambda

```
invoke(() -> "done");
```

The fact that you only have

```
"done"
```

makes the lambda *value compatible*. The body of the lambda, which doesn't appear to be an executable statement, implicitly becomes

```
{ return "done";}
```

Now, since `Runnable#run()` doesn't have a return value and `Callable#call()` does, the latter will be chosen.

Say you had written

```
invoke(() -> System.out.println());
```

instead, the lambda would be resolved to an instance of type `Runnable`, since there is no expression that could be used a return value.